# xsl loop with new name for template tag

Tags: xslt

I am trying to use a loop iteration in xslt. I want to loop through all the text with tei of "orgName", and generate a different popover-body for each one. I hope it would be something like (div class="Org-popover-body-1),(div class="Org-popover-body-2)... What should I put in ??? Thanks beforehand.

```
  <xsl:template match="tei:orgName">
    <xsl:for-each select="orgName">
      <a class="orgName" id="orgNameinfo" data-toggle="popover-2" data-trigger="fcours" data-popover-content-2="#a2" data-placement="right">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@key" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      </a>
    <div id="a2" class="hidden">
      <div class="popover-heading2">Orgnization Information <span style="float:right;cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-times" data-toggle="popover"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="Org-popover-body-???">
      </div>
    </div>  
  </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need are [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates), so you would write this...

```
<div class="Org-popover-body-{position()}">
```

You probably want to do this in the id of the hidden div to (to avoid multiple divs with the same id)

```
<div id="a{position()}" class="hidden">
```

And similarly in the `data-popover-content-2` attribute

```
... data-popover-content-2="#a{position()}" ...
```